# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' Python databases

Tags: python, dataframe

```
EditCalc = input('What file do you want to modify')
Dept = input('What department?')
EditCalc = int(EditCalc)



month = 'Jan'
if EditCalc % 12 == 0:
    month = 'Jan'
if EditCalc % 12 == 1:
    month = 'Feb'
if EditCalc % 12 == 2:
    month = 'Mar'
if EditCalc % 12 == 3:
    month = 'Apr'
if EditCalc % 12 == 4:
    month = 'May'
if EditCalc % 12 == 5:
    month = 'Jun'
if EditCalc % 12 == 6:
    month = 'Jul'
if EditCalc % 12 == 7:
    month = 'Aug'
if EditCalc % 12 == 8:
    month = 'Sep'
if EditCalc % 12 == 9:
    month = 'Oct'
if EditCalc % 12 == 10:
    month = 'Nov'
if EditCalc % 12 == 11:
    month = 'Dec'

year = EditCalc//12 + 14

editheadercalc= str(month)+'-'+str(year)+'\nQty'


editfile = pd.read_csv(str(EditCalc)+'.csv', encoding='latin-1')
editfilevalues= editfile.loc[editfile['Customer'].str.contains(Dept, na=False), str(editheadercalc)] 
editfilevalues = editfilevalues.fillna(int(0))
int_series = editfilevalues.astype(int) 
calculated_series = editfilevalues.apply(lambda x: x*1.3) 


print(editfilevalues)
```

So in this code I am trying to manipulate data from a specific file. The user input is used to find the file, and then find a specific header based on the file that I entered, because I need that header based on the file number. for example file 53 is June 2018 sales forecast, so I need to find the header in the csv file that has that and I want to multiply those values by whatever i desire ( to make an adjusted forecast) However I am getting the following error:

```
return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 456, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
File "pandas/_libs/src\util.pxd", line 142, in util.set_value_at_unsafe
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '    '
```

Any ideaS? I don't know why Im getting this error, and every other post on stackoverflow concerning this has not helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, why is pressing enter being interpreted as an empty string? Like how else should I tell the program which department to look at

Comment: @roganjosh Yes i am pressing enter after each input. Also I editted the trackeback error. Thanks

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, thanks, although that does help with that formatting, it does not prevent the error from occurring unfortunately.

Comment: @roganjosh Although that link is helpful, I am not entering wrong userinput :(

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you try to convert something to an integer that cannot be converted to an integer, for example an empty string `''`. You can recreate it yourself by running `int('')` or `int('this is not an integer')`.

To fix this, you can use a try/except block when converting your input string to an integer. You can catch the error and have the user try a different input until they submit a valid input. For example:

```
while True:
    x = input('Input a number: ')
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a number')
    else:
        print('The number you selected is {}'.format(x))
        break
```

Comment: I don't believe that is the issue, because when I hard code the line 
editfile = pd.read_csv(str(EditCalc)+'.csv', encoding='latin-1')
with just: editfile = pd.read_csv(53+'.csv', encoding='latin-1') it works